# How could I find the most correlated stock within a time period?

Tags: r, time-series, finance, stock

I got a large dataset and was required to find the top 3 stocks that were most correlated to a specific one.

Say the dataset was given below:
df:

```
Name             Date             Price

apple            2016-10-01        1.5

banana           2016-10-01        2.5

apple            2016-10-08        1.7

banana           2016-10-08        2.2

apple            2016-10-15        1.6

banana           2016-10-15        2.4

melon            2016-10-15        5.5
```

The real data frame is much larger than this example, I wonder how I can derive a correlation matrix for several stocks within a time period, say the last 3 years.

I plan to fist convert the data frame into the form below:
[The form I want to convert the dataset to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7gcu.png)

The other problem is that I do not know how I can transfer the dataset into the form based on the date.

So I have tried:

```
IDs<-c(df$name)
m<-cbind(df[df$name=="apple",c(2,3)],df[df$name=="banana,3])
m<-cbind(m,df[df$name==IDs,3])
```

Then I got the error:
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 157, 164.

Comment: Please show your code (what have you tried so far) to give others an idea of what your thinking is?

Comment: @oaxacamatt Thanks for your reply, I have just edited the question, and if you still have anything confused, just let me know.

Comment: To convert your data frame you can use `library(tidyverse)` and `pivot_wider`: `pivot_wider(df, id_cols = Date, names_from = Name, values_from = Price)`